# Remover uma coluna da gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estou implementando uma funcionalidade em um projeto utilizando asp.net mvc e estou tentando remover algumas colunas de um gridview que eu criei na minha aplicação, o datasource do gridview é uma tabela no banco de dados, porém quero remover algumas colunas da tabela, pois estou tentando exportar esses dados para um arquivo excel e alguns itens da tabela como a chave primária não são necessários. Como eu faço pra remover as colunas a minha escolha do gridview?
Já tentei coisas como:

```
gv.Columns.Remove("ArquivoExcelId");
```

tambem tentei:

```
gv.Columns[0].Visible = false;
```

mas os 2 geraram erro, como se os parametros passados fossem incompativeis ou algo do tipo, alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Comment: Qual erro que gera? qual código você está usando para gerar o excel?

Comment: Se é asp.net mvc você não vai conseguir fazer isto via código server side. Tente ocultar a coluna usando jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo, por que você não filtra a coluna retirando-a do `select`?

Você também pode fazer a alteração via front-end, pelo `css` colocando `style = "display: none;"` na coluna.

Outra solução via `server side` é montar as colunas através do `RowDataBound`.
Se preferir, trate o DataSet:

`gv.Columns.RemoveAt(0); //Index da coluna 'ArquivoExcelId'`

Ou

`gv.Columns.Remove("ArquivoExcelId");`

Comment: Valeu Marllon, consegui fazer utilizando uma operação ternaria no linq, eu não queria no select pq tem outras coisas na aplicação que isso tava impactando, de qualquer forma muito obrigado!

Comment: Show de bola, `joao igor`! Se puder, edita sua pergunta com a solução para ajudar outras pessoas que tiverem a mesma dúvida.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta isso:

```
private void BindDataAndInitializeColumns()
{
    dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = customersDataSet;
    dataGridView1.Columns.Remove("Fax");
    dataGridView1.Columns["CustomerID"].Visible = false;
}
```

Tirado do MSDN.

Ou com o `gv.Columns.RemoveAt(x)`;

Comment: Tentei ja essa solução e não tinha conseguido, eu não sabia, mas da pra fazer if utilizando operação ternaria no linq, consegui através disso selecionar o que eu queria, obrigado.